# consume Api on the Quasar page

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I'm creating a page for an App with the Quasar Framework, how do I consume this Api on the Quasar page (template)?
Could you help me make a v-for on the cards? How would you get the (articles title) of this object.
Quasar version 1.0, axios plugin.

Html:

```
<div class="" v-for="(articles, index) in posts" :key="index">

                  {{ articles.title }}
          </div>

        <script>
        export default {
          name: 'Novidades',
          data () {
            return {
              posts: []
            }
          },
          mounted () {
            this.getPosts()
          },
          methods: {
            getPosts () {
                this.$axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2019-05-04&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=4feb77b8660e4904a51ecbcae805ce03')
                .then((resp) => {
                  this.posts = resp.data
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.error(err)
                })
              }
            }
           }
           </script>
```

Comment: ok, I changed api and left an example that has in the site new api

Comment: Publishing your api key is not the best approach. Beware.

Comment: I moved from api, this is the example of the site newsapi.org/
Mine is similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It seems that is a problem with how you manipulate JSON that you received.

It's easy to see that you have an array inside object received that is called "articles". And each element has a title. So basically what you have to do is, get this articles and v-for inside of it.

The code could be like

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(article, index) in articles" :key="index">{{ article.title }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Novidades",
  data() {
    return {
      articles: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getArticles();
  },
  methods: {
    getArticles() {
      this.$http
        .get(
          "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2019-05-04&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=4feb77b8660e4904a51ecbcae805ce03"
        )
        .then(resp => {
          this.articles = resp.data.articles;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And the code is running in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-wf6tr